# How is a bitmapped vector trie faster than a plain vector?

Tags: scala, data-structures, clojure, functional-programming, jvm

It's [supposedly faster](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Functional-Data-Structures-in-Scala) than a vector, but I don't really understand how locality of reference is supposed to help this (since a vector is by definition the most locally packed data possible -- every element is packed next to the succeeding element, with no extra space between).

Is the benchmark assuming a specific usage pattern or something similar?

How this is possible?

Comment: I edited the tags so that your question get noticed by the people more likely to be capable of answering it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a lot of good stuff in the other answers but nobdy answers your question. The PersistenVectors are only fast for lots of random lookups by index (when the array is big). "How can that be?" you might ask. "A normal flat array only needs to move a pointer, the PersistentVector has to go through multiple steps."

The answer is "Cache Locality".

The cache always gets a range from memory. If you have a big array it does not fit the cache. So if you want to get item x and item y you have to reload the whole cache. That's because the array is always sequential in memory.

Now with the PVector that's diffrent. There are lots of small arrays floating around and the JVM is smart about that and puts them close to each other in memory. So for random accesses this is fast; if you run through it sequentially it's much slower.

I have to say that I'm not an expert on hardware or how the JVM handles cache locality and I have never benchmarked this myself; I am just retelling stuff I've heard from other people :)

Edit: mikera mentions that too.

Edit 2: See this talk about Functional Data-Structures, skip to the last part if you are only intrested in the vector. http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Functional-Data-Structures-in-Scala

Answer (score 12):

bitmapped vector tries *aren't* strictly faster than normal vectors, at least not at everything. It depends on what operation you are considering.

Conventional vectors are faster, for example, at accessing a data element at a specific index. It's hard to beat a straight indexed array lookup. And from a cache locality perspective, big arrays are pretty good if all you are doing is looping over them sequentially.

However a bitmapped vector trie will be much faster for other operations (thanks to structural sharing) - for example creating a new copy with a single changed element without affecting the original data structure is O(log32 n) vs. O(n) for a traditional vector. That's a huge win.

Here's an excellent video well worth watching on the topic, which includes a lot of the motivation of why you might want these kind of structures in your language: [Persistent Data Structures and Managed References](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Value-Identity-State-Rich-Hickey) (talk by Rich Hickey).

Comment: Your explanation makes complete sense (+1), but are you sure that's what they were referring to? The guy who was saying "BMTs beat ArrayList" was pretty excited... and it wouldn't be so exciting if it was "copy the whole list" versus "change one element". Is that really what he meant?

Comment: I think it beats ArrayList when you do random access on very big data.

Comment: @JoeLehmann No, I don't think so. A bitmapped vector is a tree which by its definition can not have faster random access than a plain array (no matter how big are data).

Answer (score 10):

A bitmapped vector trie (aka a persistent vector) is a data structure invented by Rich Hickey for Clojure, that has been implementated in Scala since 2010 (v 2.8). It is its clever **bitwise indexing** strategy that allows for highly efficient access and modification of large data sets.

From [**Understanding Clojure's Persistent Vectors**](http://hypirion.com/musings/understanding-persistent-vector-pt-1) :

> Mutable vectors and ArrayLists are generally just arrays which grows
> and shrinks when needed. This works great when you want mutability,
> but is a big problem when you want persistence. You get slow
> modification operations because you'll have to copy the whole array
> all the time, and it will use a lot of memory. It would be ideal to
> somehow avoid redundancy as much as possible without losing
> performance when looking up values, along with fast operations. That
> is exactly what Clojure's persistent vector does, and it is done
> through balanced, ordered trees.
>
> The idea is to implement a structure which is similar to a binary
> tree. The only difference is that the interior nodes in the tree have
> a reference to at most two subnodes, and does not contain any elements
> themselves. The leaf nodes contain at most two elements. The elements
> are in order, which means that the first element is the first element
> in the leftmost leaf, and the last element is the rightmost element in
> the rightmost leaf. For now, we require that all leaf nodes are at the
> same depth[2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mS264h8KGwk). As an example, take a look at the tree below: It has
> the integers 0 to 8 in it, where 0 is the first element and 8 the
> last. The number 9 is the vector size:
>
> [image]
>
> If we wanted to add a new element to the end of this vector and we
> were in the mutable world, we would insert 9 in the rightmost leaf
> node, like this:
>
> [image]
>
> But here's the issue: We cannot do that if we want to be persistent.
> And this would obviously not work if we wanted to update an element!
> We would need to copy the whole structure, or at least parts of it.
>
> To minimize copying while retaining full persistence, we perform path
> copying: We copy all nodes on the path down to the value we're about
> to update or insert, and replace the value with the new one when we're
> at the bottom. A result of multiple insertions is shown below. Here,
> the vector with 7 elements share structure with a vector with 10
> elements:
>
> [image]
>
> The pink coloured nodes are shared between the vectors, whereas the
> brown and blue are separate. Other vectors not visualized may also
> share nodes with these vectors.

---

#### More info

Besides [**Understanding Clojure's Persistent Vectors**](http://hypirion.com/musings/understanding-persistent-vector-pt-1), the ideas behind this data structure and its use cases are also explained pretty well in David Nolen's 2014 lecture [**Immutability, interactivity & JavaScript**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mS264h8KGwk), from which the screenshot below was taken. Or if you really want to dive deeply into the technical details, see also Phil Bagwell's [**Ideal Hash Trees**](http://lampwww.epfl.ch/papers/idealhashtrees.pdf), which was the paper upon which Hickey's initial Clojure implementation was based.

[image: Persistent bitmap trie]

Answer (score 5):

What do you mean by "plain vector"? Just a flat array of items? That's great if you never update it, but if you ever change a 1M-element flat-vector you have to do a lot of copying; the tree exists to allow you to share most of the structure.

Comment: Why do you have to copy it? Can't you just modify an ArrayList directly?

Comment: Inserting or deleting an element will require moving all the subsequent elements, which is expensive.

Also, modifying an element's value won't work in a functional language, so for naive implementation, you'll have to copy all the unmodified elements.

Answer (score 2):

Short explanation: it uses the fact that the JVM optimizes so hard on read/write/copy array data structures. The key aspect IMO is that if your vector grows to a certain size index management becomes a  bottleneck . Here comes the very clever algorithm from persisted vector into play, on very large collections it outperforms the standard variant. So basically it is a functional data-structure which only performed so well because it is built up on small mutable highly optimizes JVM datastructures.
For further details see here (at the end)
http://topsy.com/vimeo.com/28760673

Comment: What exactly is the "index management" overhead here? Keeping an `int` for the size and for the capacity?

Comment: In the video I linked above multiple functional data structures are explained, the last one is the bitmapped vector trie. Watch it ( about 7 mins) it's well worth and better than I can now express on my iPhone ;)

Comment: It's the same video as the link in the question.

Comment: Hi Daniel! Thx for clarifying this. To me Daniels explanation made complete sense and was sufficient. If I remember right he also wrote some blogposts about that topic maybe those help.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the title of the talk, it's talking about *Scala* vectors, which aren't even close to "the most locally packed data possible": see source at https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_9_1_final/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Vector.scala.

Your definition only applies to Lisps (as far as I know).

Comment: It's talking about Java.util.ArrayList, if you listen to the talk.